# Devices list from avdmanager is different from Android Studio's

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I would like to create a **Pixel 4 XL** avd for example from the `avdmanager` command line but it is not part of the list of available devices contrary to Android Studio where I can choose more models.

The command to see the available devices for creating avd from avdmanager : `avdmanager list devices`

Can anyone tell me why there is a difference and how I could create my Pixel 4 XL Avd from command line ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer by myself :)

The `avdmanager` command is present in both

- `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin`
- `~/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`.

To create devices with the latest devices configuration including **Pixel 4 XL**, you have to use the `avdmanager` tool present in `cmdline-tools/bin` folder

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you mean. But you can find the AVD Manager in der Red circle I marked in Android Studio. Click to see the image.

[Click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdUFF.jpg)

Let me know if you still have trouble or issues! :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort but this is not the problem.
As i said in my post, i want to create a Pixel 4 XL in command line

Answer (score 0):

Using android studio, you can get the id for a device to use on the commandline with `avdmanager --device` by going to Device Manager -> Create device -> Right click export the device, then in that xml file under devices->device->id. For example, for the Pixel 4 XL the id is `pixel_4_xl`